# Selenium Web Driver : MalformedByteSequenceException Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am running a selenium Web Driver Project. I am taking an excel sheet as an input for my test case. I am getting the following error

```
org.testng.TestNGException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:340)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:88)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175) Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.arrangeCapacity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:172)
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:310)
... 3 more
```

Can someone please help me with this error.
Thanks

The code for Excel sheet Driver is

```
package com.bigMachines.TCL.ExcelShhetDataProvider;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;
import org.testng.Assert;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class ExcelSheetDriver {

    private Sheet wrksheet;
    private Workbook wrkbook =null;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> dict= new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    //Create a Constructor
    public ExcelSheetDriver(String ExcelSheetPath){ 
        try {
            wrkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(ExcelSheetPath));
            wrksheet = wrkbook.getSheet(0);
            columnDictionary();
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    //Returns the Number of Rows
    public int rowCount()
    {
        return wrksheet.getRows();
    }

    //Returns the Cell value by taking row and Column values as argument
    public String readCell(int column,int row)
    {
        return wrksheet.getCell(column,row).getContents();
    }

    public String readCell(String columnName,int row)
    {
        return readCell(getColumnNo(columnName), row);
    }

    //Create Column Dictionary to hold all the Column Names
    private void columnDictionary()
    {
        //Iterate through all the columns in the Excel sheet and store the value in Hashtable
        for(int col=0;col<wrksheet.getColumns();col++)
        {
            dict.put(readCell(col,0), col);
        }
    }

    //Read Column Names
    public int getColumnNo(String colName)
    {
        try {
            int value;
            value = ((Integer) dict.get(colName)).intValue();
            return value;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return (0);

        }
    }
    public Set<String> getColumnNameList(){
        return dict.keySet();
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

The link to the testing XML is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/46023159/testng.xml).

Comment: Show your code which is giving this exception?

Comment: The error message is quite clear: "Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence". I guess there's some encoding problems. It would help if you can show the code.

Comment: @Abhi_Mishra can u please check the edited code

Answer (score 1):

Given the stack trace, it looks like the problem actually has nothing to do with your code. It looks like it's in the TestNG XML file you're using to set up the test suite.

Check that XML file - my guess is that it's declaring itself to be UTF-8, but is *actually* some other encoding.

Comment: I checked the XML file. It has a declaration in which encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: What do i need to do now? Should I remove this encoding?

Comment: @KingJames: No, you should make sure that the content is *actually* in UTF-8. (You've given us no indication where you've looked it it, or what the encoding is.)

Comment: my testing.xml has this line <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: Thats not enough - still the file can be encoded differently.

Comment: @KingJames: As Pavel says, it's the *actual contents* which is important. Can you upload the XML somewhere so that we could look at it?

Comment: @JonSkeet please check the above file. I changed encoding to UTF-8 also using Notepad but still the same error.

Comment: @KingJames: The file looks okay to me. Have you had TestNG working in other situations?

Comment: I just created a new file n wrote the XML in it and it worked. It's weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the existing jar of testng in your project with some other jar.

It looks like the xml parser is causing this exception while parsing TestNG XML file.

**UPDATED:**

If you are using eclipse:

```
Right click on xml file and go to Properties.
There will be an option for Text File Encoding.
Check that it is set as UTF-8.
If not then made it as UTF-8.
```

Hope this would help you.

Comment: I tried with another jar file. It is giving me the same error.

Comment: It is by default UTF-8 only.

Answer (score 0):

Although your XML file has proper declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Its not enough. The XML file can be still encoded differently. Here is what you should try:

1. Download [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (opensource)
2. Open your XML file
3. Click Format - Encode in UTF-8. See screen:
   [image]
4. Save file and try again

Ofcourse you can skip 1 and use your preferred trext editing program. I know how to do it in Notepad++ so thats why I propose this solution

Comment: I tried that also.. same error
Here is the link to the XML File https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46023159/testng.xml